# Data augmentation parameters

Tags: deep-learning, keras, tensorflow, computer-vision, convolutional-neural-network

When I use data augmentation to increase the train dataset, should I use all augmentation techniques (parameters in [keras](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/))?

Which data augmentation parameters should use with `flow_from_directory`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This entirely depends on your data!

**Generally, the more augmentation, the more situations your model will be exposed to during training and therefore the more robust it will be when being tested on unseen data.**

However, what if we for example were working on a model for self driving cars? Using the `vertical_flip` just doesn't make sense, because the car will (hopefully!) be er be driving along on its roof.

I would suggest starting with no augmentation and slowly adding one possibility at a time. For example, you record an accuracy of 80% with no augmentation. Then add`featurewise_normalizatiom` and `featurewise_std_normalization` giving you an accuracy of 85%. Then adding `horizontal_flip` gets you to 90%. Finally you try adding `zca_whitening` and that send you back down to 86%.

The reverse approach may also work well for you, starting with all augmentation parameters turned on and removing them one by one. In any case, it is completely dependent on your specific problem and your available data.  [Keras' ImageDataGenerator has a long list of parameters,](https://keras.io/preprocessing/image/#imagedatagenerator-class) so having a think about what makes sense will save you a lot of time.